# XSL - Maths with xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to know how do you display the following in XML using XSL?

```
displaying this formula:
(value1 * 5 + value2 * 4 + value3 * 3 + value4 * 2 + value5 * 1 / value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5)
```

here is where you get the values from:

```
<ratings>
<book>
    <title>Doctor Sleep</title>
    <author>Stephen King</author>
    <userRatings outOf="5">
        <numUsers vote="5">13411</numUsers> <!-- The number of users who voted 5 out of 5 -->
        <numUsers vote="4">14794</numUsers> <!-- The number of users who voted 4 out of 5 -->
        <numUsers vote="3">5359</numUsers> <!-- etc. -->
        <numUsers vote="2">974</numUsers>
        <numUsers vote="1">361</numUsers>
        <!-- total = 34899 -->
    </userRatings>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Gone Girl</title>
    <author>Gillian Flynn</author>
    <userRatings outOf="5">
        <numUsers vote="5">95595</numUsers>
        <numUsers vote="4">140217</numUsers>
        <numUsers vote="3">61642</numUsers>
        <numUsers vote="2">16923</numUsers>
        <numUsers vote="1">6225</numUsers>
        <!-- total = 320602 -->
    </userRatings>
</book>
</ratings>
```

this is what i have so far:

```
<average>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('ratings.xml')/ratings/book[title = $compareTitles]">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(userRatings/numUsers * userRatings/numUsers/@vote) div sum(userRatings/numUsers)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</average>
```

i tried using variables, but found out that you can't manipulate a defined variable and that it is fixed when declared.

**EDIT**

```
<average>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('ratings.xml')/ratings/book[title = $compareTitles]">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(((userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '1'] * 1) +
                                 (userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '2'] * 2) +
                                 (userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '3'] * 3) +
                                 (userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '4'] * 4) +
                                 (userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '5'] * 5))
                                 div (userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '5'] +
                                 userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '4'] +
                                 userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '3'] +
                                 userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '2'] +
                                 userRatings/numUsers[@vote = '1']),'0.##')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</average>
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? You seem to have solved your task...

Comment: i wanted code to show me the result of the formula in the beginning of the questeion

Comment: Your solution is the best you can do for XSLT 1.0, though in XSLT 2.0 you can shorten it using an expression like `sum(userRatings/numUsers/(@vote * .)) div sum(userRatings/numUsers)`

Comment: nope... ohwell.. if it works, it works. but tx anyway

Comment: Would you consider answering your own question (to formally close it)?